# All homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ are isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I came across a problem which asked to prove that the ring of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}$ (viewed as an abelian group) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e $\operatorname{End}\mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}$. Supposing this was true, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field this will imply that $\operatorname{End} \mathbb{Q}$ is a field. This means every element has an inverse or more specifically every element(non zero) in $\operatorname{End} \mathbb{Q}$ is an isomorphism. So given any group homorphism from $\phi:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$, it turns out to be an isomorphism. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: I don't  understand what your problem is. It is well known that a ring homomorphism from a field to another field is injective

Comment: Why is $\operatorname{End}\mathbb{Q}$ a field?

Comment: Unique divisibility implies that there is only one ring homomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}$ to itself. Are you sure you do not mean to ask about endomorphisms of the underlying abelian group.

Comment: Yea. That's what I meant. I edited it.

Comment: any nonzero homomorphism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, an abelian group morphism $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ is automatically $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, and we know what $K$-linear maps $K\to K$ are for a field $K$.

A group morphism $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is necessarily of the form $x\mapsto rx$, so yes, unless it's $0$, it's an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense now.